# Adding items to an Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

So i am trying to add items to an arraylist, However when I try to write the add method the IDE gives me an error that I'm passing "name, cusip and ticker wrong. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong here? Thank you in advance.

Here is my ETF class

```
package fundProject;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class ETF extends AbstractETF {
    private String name;
    private int cusip;
    private int ticker;


    public ETF(String name, int cusip, int ticker) {
        this.name = getName();
        this.cusip = getCusip();
        this.ticker = getTicker();


    }


    public int getCusip() {
        System.out.println("Please enter the Cusip of the ETF");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        cusip = sc.nextInt();
        return cusip;
    }

    public int getTicker() {
        System.out.println("Please enter the Ticker of the ETF");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ticker = sc.nextInt();
        return ticker;
    }

    public String getName() {
        System.out.println("Please enter the Name  of the ETF");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = sc.next();
        return name;

    }
}
```

And here is my main class

```
package fundProject;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class mainClass {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<ETF> etfArrayList = new ArrayList<ETF>();

        etfArrayList.add(new ETF(name, cusip, ticker));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are name, cusip, and ticker declared?

Comment: ^^^ @RobertMoskal is right, you need those values declared, and they need to BE something, they need a value or they are useless. You didnt think this through mate, research and attempt to debug before you post a question. Just a solid tip. After reading through the answers, i suggest you delete this question as it does not help the community and should not have been posted in the first place.

Comment: Your `ETF` class is very confusing. First it calls [overrideable method from a constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3404369/2071828). Then, whenever anyone tries to use the [accessors](http://java.about.com/od/workingwithobjects/a/accessormutator.htm) for its variables, the thing tries to read a new value from a `Scanner`! I would seriously rethink your design. Also [**always close your resources**](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b131/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not defining what exactly `name` `cusip` and `ticker` are. You should declare them somewhere first.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<ETF> etfArrayList = new ArrayList<ETF>();
    String name = "John Doe";
    int cusip = 1;
    int ticker = 1;

    etfArrayList.add(new ETF(name, cusip, ticker));
    }
}
```

You also need to rewrite your constructor for those arguments to be accepted:

```
public ETF(String name, int cusip, int ticker) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cusip = cusip;
    this.ticker = ticker;
}
```

Overall your ETF class could use another look-over. It's not easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

First, you haven't defined the variables `name`, `cusip`, and `ticker` in the `mainClass` class, so the compiler generates an error here.

However, you don't even use those 3 parameters in your `ETF` constructor.

I would do one of the following things:

- Eliminate the parameters to the constructor, and don't pass anything into the constructor.
- Or, move the code to ask the user for input to `main`, so you can pass those variables into the constructor.  The constructor would simply copy the values.